# Programming Apple M1 chip GPU

Tags: multithreading, gpu

I've used CUDA to program an Nvidia GPU but I
want to program my Apple M1 GPU. I can't find
any tools online to do this. CUDA is not for mac.
The Apple M1 GPU should be able to execute
25,000 threads simultaneously. Preferably this
would be a C-like language similar to CUDA.

Comment: Metal or OpenCL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard and portable way of computing on GPU is to use **OpenCL**.
However, using OpenCL on Apple machines has been [deprecated in 2018](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/OpenCL_MacProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html). Since, Apple recommend developers to use **Metal** instead (which only works on Apple machines).

Comment: Apple no longer support OpenCL. It was deprecated in 2018

Comment: @talonmies You are right about the deprecation. I will add a note for this. However, AFAIK Apple machines still able to run OpenCL codes so it is still supported (for example, the GeekBench benchmark tool use OpenCL to successfully measure the Apple M1 GPU performance).